# Positioning a Gameobject to stay in screen center always

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, gameobject

I'm trying to position a gameobject to stay at the center of the screen always. I'm using the following code to do so,

```
sphere.SetActive(true);
Vector3 lookAtPosition = FirstPersonCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, FirstPersonCamera.nearClipPlane));
sphere.transform.position = lookAtPosition;
```

But for some reason, the gameobject is not visible at all with the above code.

So, I tried to raycast it and make it visible.

Following is the corresponding code,

```
TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon | TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;

TrackableHit hit;
if (Frame.Raycast(screenCenter.x, screenCenter.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
{
    var pose = hit.Pose;

    sphere.SetActive(true);
    sphere.transform.position = pose.position;
    sphere.transform.up = pose.up;
}
```

The gameobject shows up occasionally with the above code but it is not centered exactly to the screen and it is not showing up forever. How can I be able to sort it out?

Comment: The original code only does a "lookat" it didnt move it.  Also remember depending on the pivot point of your object, "center" is biased by that, so if the object is a 1.8unit man, and your point is his feet, his feet are in the cener, not his belly.  At runtime, look in scene view and see where your object is ending up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It could be that your object is on top of the camera and outside in its field of view
- A problem on its sorting layer

A screenshot of your inspector and scene window might help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to use the following code (this is an example code for ARCore SDK in Android Studio):

```
static const Pose oneMeterAway = Pose.makeTranslation(0, 0, -1);
objectPose = camera.getPose().extractTranslation().compose(oneMeterAway);
```

**And then you need to update it every frame**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know. I'm just showing an approach (and using ARCore SDK as example code).